# Deduplication with StormCrawler

Tags: solr, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I see that Document Deduplication is not supported yet in Stormcrawler. Is this something in the pipeline for future? I am asking this because I see that the Signature metadata can be added in the Status core and may be that can be used to remove the duplicates with the same signature value before indexing. Just a thought if I am thinking in the right direction?

Thanks,

Suman

Answer (score 0):

[MD5SignatureParseFilter](http://stormcrawler.net/docs/api/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/parse/filter/MD5SignatureParseFilter.html) computes a signature based on the content of the document. This is used for the AdaptiveScheduling to determine whether a document has changed. You could index the same metadatum into SOLR for deduplicating, for instance by using it as a primary key for the document. 
Since StormCrawler sees each document in isolation, it is difficult to act on the duplicates in the same way as Nutch does with MapReduce. One option would be to have an external process resolving the duplicates straight onto the indexing backend (e.g. SOLR) but that would be outside of StormCrawler and backend dependent.

In a nutshell, if you can use the hash as a primary key for dedup then you have all the elements you need already but that's probably as far as things will go with StormCrawler.

> I see that Document Deduplication is not supported yet in Stormcrawler.

where did you see that?

Comment: Apache Nutch is a great tool though, which we used for years with many of our customers at DigitalPebble, and it can also do things that StormCrawler cannot currently do out of the box like deduplicating or advanced scoring like PageRank.  http://stormcrawler.net/faq/  ,   https://dzone.com/articles/the-battle-of-the-crawlers-apache-nutch-vs-stormcr

Comment: Having signature metadatum as primary key might be an issue since when the content of the document changes then the signature value will also change.

Comment: thanks @msuman49 I remembered writing something like that but could not remember where. 
re-primary key: indeed.

Comment: what do you mean by re-primary key: indeed ?